# one line hash creation in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, hash

How can I, very simply construct a hash in ruby using something simple like "times"

I have a @date (ie = Date.today) and then a number of days... say 5

```
5.times { |i| @date_range[:day] = (@date+i).strftime("%Y-%m-%d") }
```

I know there's got to be something super simple that's missing.

Thanks...

Comment: What do you need the hash for? Cryptography? Fast indexing? Duplicate detection?

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. You're assigning the same hash key to five different values. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Looks like you're trying to do too much in one line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Date` objects are also `Comparable`, so you could construct a `Range`:

```
@range = @date..(@date + 10)
```

You can iterate over it easily and output the results. If you want to access a particular date numerically, you can do:

```
@date_range = (@date..(@date + 10)).to_a
@date_range[1]
```

Or if you really need to format the dates beforehand, as in your example:

```
@date_range = (@date..(@date + 10)).map { |date| date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") }
@date_range[1]
```

The final line would be equivalent in use to your `@date_range[1]` (equal to tomorrow / `@date + 1`), even though it is actually an `Array` rather than a `Hash`. A `Hash` with sequential numeric keys doesn't make a lot of sense: you get those for free with an `Array` *and*, as a bonus, the order of the values is preserved. In my opinion, using `Range`s to start with slightly clarifies the intent, but it's not a spectacular difference.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work...

```
(1..10).each { |i| @date_range[i] = (@date+i).strftime("%Y-%m-%d") }
```

Answer (score 1):

You want a hash that contains today's date plus the hash key?

```
today = Date.today
days = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = (today + k).strftime( '%Y-%m-%d' ) }
```

This has the advantage of not being limited to a few days. It'll work for any key. Plus, the calculation happens only once per key and as needed.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `collect` to create an array in one line, but I'm not sure where your hash comes in...

```
@date_range = 5.times.collect { |i| (@date+i).strftime("%Y-%m-%d") }
```